# How to send an email with Python without enabling 2-fa and allow less secure app options in the sender Gmail account?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gmail, gmail-api, smtplib

I am trying to develop a feature for sending an email from an gmail account with an own domain. For example: person1@companyname.com

The requirement is that I can't enable the 2 factor authentication in the google account and allow less secure apps neither.

So, what will be the best approach for this? I have seen a tutorial on Youtube but they use a credential.json or client.json files for authentication without explaining the proper way to get these files or their contents.

This is the code I have so far:

```
 # Sending email
           try:
               password = 'appPasswordIsSupposedtoBePlacedHereButIAmNotAllowedToUseit'
               sender_email = 'person1@companyname.com'
               recipient_email = ['person2@companyname.com', 'testemail@gmail.com'] 
               subject = 'blablba'
               body = 'blabla'
               em= EmailMessage()
               em['From']= sender_email
               em['To'] = ", ".join(recipient_email)
               em['subject'] = subject
               em.set_content(body)

               context = ssl.create_default_context()

               with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, context=context) as smtp:
                   smtp.login(sender_email, password)
                   smtp.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, em.as_string())

           except Exception as e:
               errors = errores + ' Error while sending the email: ' + str(e)
               logging.warning(errors)
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually have two options.

1. create a google workspace account for your domain, then you can use a service account and domain wide deligation to do this with the gmail api.
2. Use Xoauth2 to authorize the user and store the refresh token.

[2023: How I access GMail SMTP without enabling 2fa. (Python oauth2)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1U3pwIBAIM)

Sample Xoauth2

```
from __future__ import print_function

import base64
import os.path
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

# user token storage
USER_TOKENS = 'token.json'

# application credentials
CREDENTIALS = 'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json'


def getToken() -> str:
    creds = None

    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(USER_TOKENS):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(USER_TOKENS, SCOPES)
        creds.refresh(Request())
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(USER_TOKENS, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    return creds.token


def generate_oauth2_string(username, access_token) -> str:
    auth_string = 'user=' + username + '\1auth=Bearer ' + access_token + '\1\1'
    return base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode('ascii')).decode('ascii')

def send_email(host, port, subject, msg, sender, recipients):
    access_token = getToken()
    auth_string = generate_oauth2_string(sender, access_token)

    msg = MIMEText(msg)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)

    server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
    server.starttls()
    server.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + auth_string)
    server.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()


def main():
    host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    port = 587

    user = "xxx@gmail.com"
    recipient = "xxx@gmail.com"
    subject = "Test email Oauth2"
    msg = "Hello world"
    sender = user
    recipients = [recipient]
    send_email(host, port, subject, msg, sender, recipients)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The access token and refresh token will be stored in  'token.json'.    Just create installed app credentials on google developer console and set the app to production if its single user you dont need to verify it .

Comment: Yes, I saw your tutorial before. It seems that this solution (xoauth2) breaks my web application since a previous get request for Google Sheets API is returning an Internal Error response (code 500). By the other hand, by using this method does the user need to give permission everytime the sending email function triggers?

Comment: First off this sample is for installed app, so it wont authorize if you are hosting it on a web server.  For example I use it for sending automated forgot password emails.  I authorize the code once locally then upload token.json along with the code to my server.    It will then send emails from my account automatically.    Without requesting authorization of a user.    If you want to allow users to send emails then you should be using the gmail api with Oauth2, you can add that to your existing sheets api request scopes.